# connect to access codeigniter then export to mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

whats wrong with this code, keep getting "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings." when trying to connect with access database

```
public function update_dbx(){
    $loc='Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='.base_url('database\simardi.mdb');
  $confd['hostname'] = $loc;
  $confd['username'] = '';
  $confd['password'] = '';
  $confd['database'] = $loc;
  $confd['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
  $confd['dbprefix'] = '';
  $confd['pconnect'] = TRUE;
  $confd['db_debug'] = TRUE;
  $confd['cache_on'] = FALSE;
  $confd['cachedir'] = '';
  $confd['char_set'] = 'utf8';
  $confd['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
  $confd['swap_pre'] = '';
  $confd['autoinit'] = TRUE;
  $confd['stricton'] = FALSE;

    $CI = &get_instance();
    $this->db2 = $CI->load->database('db2', $confd);
    $qryx = $this->db2->query("SELECT * FROM INAKTIFMASTER");
    foreach($qryx->result() as $data){
        $this->db->insert('INAKTIFMASTER',$data);
        //print_r($data);
    }
```

im trying to export mysql db from accces via upload

i have default and "db2" database config in my database.php

edit

```
  $db['db2']['hostname'] = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\xampp\htdocs\site\database\data.mdb';
   $db['db2']['username'] = '';
   $db['db2']['password'] = '';
   $db['db2']['database'] = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\xampp\htdocs\site\database\data.mdb';
```

$db['db2']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';

i need those work with base_url

Comment: `$confd['username'] = "root";` missing

Comment: still getting error sir

Comment: Yur host is local host?

Comment: $loc is equal to localhost??

Comment: `$confd['database'] = "db2";` use this also

Comment: 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\xampp\htdocs\site\database\data.mdb';

in my database.php
thats working perfectly, but need to set base_url
'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='.base_url('database\data.mdb'); and  not working , i dont know how to configure it with controller

Comment: Base URL is not equal to `DBQ=C:\xampp\htdocs\site\`

Comment: please, i edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are using `base_url()`. And this is not equal to;

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\
```

For access on Directory you can use

```
__DIR__."database/data.mdb"
```

Before executing use `var_dump(__DIR__);` and check what are you getting.

Comment: @ArrmyYuwandono: good work brother.. if it helps u plz accept http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work